# JQuery Load, Notify Calling Window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the JQuery event "load" to notify when the entire html window has loaded as well as all scripts have executed.  I understand the intention of this function is to be used with in the document.ready event.  However, I have one window spawning other windows and I need for the parent window to be notified when the child window is completely finished loading so I can insert saved content.  Can anyone please guide me in the right direction.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the loaded event using `load` event

```
$('#iframe').on('load', function (e) {
   //.......
});
```

Comment: That function only works if it's called within the window's script tags.  If you wanted to get notified outside of the window (i.e. window notifies the parent who created it that is has finished loading) this function you referenced does not work.

Comment: You can call this function from the parent window to get the notifications.

Comment: @mvcNewbie, On IE, you cannot set event handler from outside. Try `<iframe id="myFrame" onload="myFunction();"></iframe>`